# Do the Dual Wielder and Crossbow Expert feats work together?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranged-attack

Can I attack 3 times with two hand crossbows if I have the Dual Wielder feat and the Crossbow Expert feat?

The Crossbow Expert feat says:

> - You ignore the loading quality of crossbows with which you are proficient.
> - Being within 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged attack rolls.
> - When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a loaded hand crossbow you are holding.

The Dual Wielder feat says:

> - When wielding a weapon in both hands, you gain a +1 bonus to AC
> - Once on your turn, when you take the attack action and are two-weapon fighting, you may make one attack as a bonus action.
> - While two-weapon fighting, you may make a two-weapon attack in place of a reaction weapon attack, such as an opportunity attack.

Comment: Part of your confusion may come from using the wrong rules: your screen captures were not the actual game text. Somebody has helpfully edited the correct rules in for you.

Comment: @T.J.L.: I've reverted the quotes to transcribed versions of those originally shown in the screenshots OP included, as they're part of the source of OP's confusion (and the change would invalidate part of the existing answer).

Answer (score 11):

No. You only have one bonus action per round, and both Two-Weapon Fighting and Crossbow Expert use your bonus action.

The [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) rule states:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon
>   that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack
>   with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other
>   hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus
>   attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>
> If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon,
>   instead of making a melee attack with it.

As you can see, Two-Weapon Fighting (which the Dual Wielder feat enhances) grants you an additional attack that uses your bonus action. The additional attack granted by the Crossbow Expert feat uses your bonus action as well. And you can only take one [bonus action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) per turn:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

---

As a side note, wherever you are pulling your information from is not correctly quoting the descriptions of the feats.

The description of the [Crossbow Expert](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crossbow-expert) feat should read (PHB, p. 165):

> Thanks to extensive practice with the crossbow, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - You ignore the loading property of crossbows with which you are proficient.
> - Being within 5 feet of a hostile creature doesn’t impose disadvantage on your ranged attack rolls.
> - When you use the Attack action and attack with a one-handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a hand crossbow you are holding.

The description of the [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/dual-wielder) feat should read (PHB, p. 165):

> You master fighting with two weapons, gaining the following benefits:
>
> - You gain a +1 bonus to AC while you are wielding a separate melee weapon in each hand.
> - You can use two-weapon fighting even when the one-handed melee weapons you are wielding aren't light.
> - You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

Comment: Another flaw in OP's plan that you didn't point out: Two-Weapon Fighting requires wielding two one-handed melee weapons, so you can't use TWF while wielding two hand crossbows (or even one).

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if it more strongly emphasized the fact that the original poster is looking at house rules. It's not an aside, it's the core of the confusion.